# Spring project error configuration with hibernate and postgres db

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I have a problem with my new Project , I receive this error that I can not solve, I loaded the project on github I think it's a configuration problem.

https://github.com/DeAngelisLuca/Traccialo

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://localhost/traccialo 
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop

spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver

spring.jpa.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update

spring.jpa.hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults false
```

part of stackTrace

```
2018-04-15 19:54:27.672  INFO 9696 --- [           main] i.d.Traccialo.ServletInitializer         : Starting ServletInitializer v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT on PC-Luca with PID 9696 (C:\Users\Luca\eclipse-workspace-professional\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\Traccialo\WEB-INF\classes started by Luca in C:\Users\Luca\Downloads\eclipse-jee-oxygen-3-win32-x86_64\eclipse)
2018-04-15 19:54:27.675  INFO 9696 --- [           main] i.d.Traccialo.ServletInitializer         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-04-15 19:54:27.752  INFO 9696 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@25b78608: startup date [Sun Apr 15 19:54:27 CEST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-04-15 19:54:28.569  INFO 9696 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'dataSource' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat; factoryMethodName=dataSource; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari; factoryMethodName=dataSource; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]]
2018-04-15 19:54:29.273  INFO 9696 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$dc6cce97] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-04-15 19:54:29.358  INFO 9696 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[.[localhost].[/Traccialo]     : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-04-15 19:54:29.358  INFO 9696 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1606 ms
2018-04-15 19:54:29.768  INFO 9696 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2018-04-15 19:54:29.769  INFO 9696 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'errorPageFilter' to: [/*]
2018-04-15 19:54:29.769  INFO 9696 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2018-04-15 19:54:29.770  INFO 9696 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2018-04-15 19:54:29.770  INFO 9696 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2018-04-15 19:54:29.770  INFO 9696 --- [           main] .s.DelegatingFilterProxyRegistrationBean : Mapping filter: 'springSecurityFilterChain' to: [/*]
2018-04-15 19:54:29.770  INFO 9696 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet dispatcherServlet mapped to [/]
2018-04-15 19:54:30.022  INFO 9696 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2018-04-15 19:54:30.153  INFO 9696 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2018-04-15 19:54:30.229  INFO 9696 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-04-15 19:54:30.264  INFO 9696 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2018-04-15 19:54:30.465  INFO 9696 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.16.Final}
2018-04-15 19:54:30.469  INFO 9696 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2018-04-15 19:54:30.562  INFO 9696 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2018-04-15 19:54:30.836  INFO 9696 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
2018-04-15 19:54:30.961  INFO 9696 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.LobCreatorBuilderImpl        : HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
```

stacktrace photo
[image]

Comment: Neither the application.properties nor the stacktrace should be posted as screenshot, but as text.

Comment: i have edit the post , thanks for the info

Comment: please add your complete error stacktrace to your question.. to know what exactly the problem here is :) Thanks

Comment: add stacktrace photo

Answer (score 1):

This exception only came when there is a mismatch of jdbc driver 4 (I think so, I have faced earlier this), As you know hibernate is a ORM tool so to create a connection it needs some meta-data information from the database.

You can disable this feature just by putting this line in `application.properties`

```
hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults = false
```

if you have `hibernate.cfg.xml` as a configuration file then you may add this line to your config file

hibernate.cfg.xml file add below property

```
<property name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults">false</property>
```

> Note :- If you see your `application.properties` key-value pair must be seperated with `=` (assignment operator). please add this to your code

Hope this will help you out. Thanks :)

Comment: have you put `=` in between key-value pair ??

Comment: sure, it was an oversight

Comment: Someone Can help me?